# Java for:each loop problem doesn't work while for loop works on the same program. Can anybody tell the difference and tell me why?

Tags: java, foreach

*Java for:each loop problem doesn't work while for loop works on the same programm.Can anybody tell the difference and tell me why?*

```
package pkgtry;
public class Try{
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                int array[] = {1,45,57,313,56,1,235,213,352323,547,441,56,2314};
                System.out.println("Ta stoixeia tou pinaka prin thn taxinomhsh: ");
                for (int i : array){
                        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                }
                System.out.println();

                Try.insertionSort(array);
                System.out.println("Ta stoixeia tou pinaka meta thn taxinomhsh: ");

                for (int i : array){
                        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                }
        }

        public static void insertionSort(int array[]){
                for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++){
                        int current = array[i];
                        int j=i;

                        while(j>0 && array[j -1]> current){
                                array[j] = array[j-1];
                                j--;
                        }
                        array[j] = current;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In here

```
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
}
```

you should not use array[i], but only i which is already the element in your array.

So try:

```
System.out.print(" " + i);
```

I guess you were thinking of this when you said it is not working, no?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for each` for this array that contains integers, 
the variable `i` is not the counter of the iterations but the actual item of the array, 

so change:

```
for (int i : array){
    System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
}
```

to

```
for (int i : array){
   System.out.print(" " + i);
}
```

Comment: Thank yoiu very much!